# Outras maneiras de fazer matriz

Tags: python

Consegui desenvolver até aqui, não se deve imprimir espaços após o último elemento de cada linha o que faz com que o exercício dê errado, alguém conhece outro método ?

```
minha_matriz= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]

def imprime_matriz(minha_matriz):
      for i in range(len(minha_matriz)):
             print(end="\n")
             for j in range(len(minha_matriz[i])):
                            print(minha_matriz[i][j], end =' ')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sim. Por exemplo, esta forma:

```
def imprime_matriz(minha_matriz):
      for linha in minha_matriz:
        print(' '.join(str(i) for i in linha))

minha_matriz= [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]                            
imprime_matriz(minha_matriz)
```

Você pode ver executando [no Ideone](http://ideone.com/25d0tv).

O que ocorre é que no seu código você imprime número por número e indica à função `print` para "trocar" o caractere de nova linha (o famoso `'\n'`) por um espaço em branco (`' '`). Ela faz isso para todos os elementos, incluindo o último. Você poderia fazer uma verificação (um `if`) para saber quando é o último e *só nesse caso* usar `end=''`, mas o jeito mais "pythônico" é usar o [`join`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_join.htm). Ele vai juntar os itens de uma lista (a linha dentro do for) separando-os com a string data, sem colocar nada no começo ou no final do resultado. :)

Comment: Muito obrigado por sua resposta, me deu um chão ... VLW

Comment: Por nada. :) Se a resposta foi útil, por favor considere [marcá-la como aceita](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: poderia me ajudar com este exercício ?
http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/186090/operador-de-subtra%C3%A7%C3%A3o-n%C3%A3o-reconhecido-no-python